# I have an error on my import angularfirestore

Tags: angular, firebase

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

> Module '"@angular/fire/firestore"' has no exported member 'AngularFirestoreCollection'.

> Module '"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/ShemmaDemo2Cart/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index"' has no default export.

> Cannot find module '@capacitor/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: What version of @angular/fire/firestore are you on? Also could be a good idea to delete node_modules and package lock and then run npm i again. I know for angular since a certain version 7.0.0 came out they changed where to : import from @angular/fire/compat/firestore';